# How do I adjust the page size such that I can fit a large header and footer into my page?

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I am using fancyhdr to create two page styles. One page, the first one, will have a memo heading. The company logo, who its going to, organization name,etc. After that, I want a more simplified header and footer. For some reason, I can get my header to fit, but the text is overflowing and knocking out my footer. I have looked at the diagram for page size and margins.

I guess simplistically I would think that headsize+footsize+textsize = pagesize. I have tried shrinking textsize but my footer still seems to disappear. I was hoping that someone could help me fix this.

Below I have a minimal example (commented however):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PAGE STYLE       %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
  {%First page definitions
    \newgeometry{left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=2.8in, bmargin=3.8in,headheight=179.1pt}
    
    
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      %                  HEADERS                             %
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

      %%%%%RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
      \fancyhead[R]{
        \begin{tabular}{r@{}c@{}l}
          \textit{To}: & Jane Doe, ABC-DE, PO 5125\\
          \textit{From}: &John Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5125\\
          &Heather Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5125\\
          &W. Sam Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5126\\
          \textit{Thru}: &Chip Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5126\\
          \textit{Phone}: &(800)867-5309\\
          \textit{Symbol}: &ABC-DEF:2021-XXXX\\
          \textit{Date}: &\today \\
        \end{tabular}
      }
          %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
      \fancyhead[LH]{\vspace{1cm}ABC-DEF:2021-XXXXX \\ \vspace{1cm}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{somepic.png}\\
                    \vspace{0.1cm}{\Large\textbf{memorandum}}\\
                    ORG-NAM, SOME ORGANIZATION
  }
  %%%%%END LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%CENTER HEADER%%%%%
  \chead[C]{}
  %%%%%END CENTER HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %                  FOOTERS                             %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  

  %%%%%%%%CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cfoot[C]{}
  %%%%%%%%END CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  %%%%%LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  \lfoot{\vspace{0cm}\fbox{
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
          \begin{center}
            {\large\textbf{BLAH}}
          \end{center}
          blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        \end{minipage}
      }%End of fbox
    }
  %%%%%END LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%

  %%%%%RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\vspace{0cm}\fbox{\raggedright
        \begin{minipage}[r]{0.4\textwidth}
          \begin{center}
            {\large \textbf{Chief Editor}}
          \end{center}
          \textbf{Brought to you by:} ME\\
          \textbf{Original:} XZ-ORG1-COMPANY\\
        \end{minipage}
      }%end of fbox
    }
    %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  
}%End of first page definitions


\fancypagestyle{otherpages}{%all otherpages
    \setlength{\headheight}{57.7pt}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %                  HEADERS                             %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  %%%%%RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
  \fancyhead[R]{\today}
  %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
  \fancyhead[LH]{\vspace{1cm}ABC-DEF: 2021-XXXXX}
  %%%%%END LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%CENTER HEADER%%%%%
   \fancyhead[C]{{\Huge\color{red}\textbf{HEAD/ER}}\\-\thepage}
   %%%%%END CENTER HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %                  FOOTERS                             %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  
  %%%%%%%%CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cfoot[C]{\Huge\color{red}\textbf{FOOT/ER}}
  %%%%%%%%END CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


  %%%%%LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  \fancyfoot[L]{}
  %%%%%END LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%

  %%%%%RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  \fancyfoot[R]{}
  %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  
}%end of all other pages


%%End of first page definition
\pagestyle{otherpages}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\begin{document}

{\Large \textbf{Subject: (U) poop}}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\Blindtext
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes to the fancy header  definitions but mostly to the implementation of the `geometry` package.

To get back the default geometry on the second page is not an easy task if you don't do it  manually, by inserting the `\restoregeometry` (which itself starts a new page) at the correct place in the text.

However, a solution using the `afterpage` package seems to work in this case (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358322/161015)

[image: a2]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{showframe} % to show margins. Comment this line to clear  <<<<
\usepackage{afterpage} % needed <<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage[letterpaper,left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=1.5in, bottom=1.2in,headheight=0.8in]{geometry} % changed <<<

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PAGE STYLE       %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{%First page definitions    
    \fancyhf{}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %                  HEADERS                             %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    %%%%%RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
    \fancyhead[R]{%% changed to align second column <<<<<<<
        \begin{tabular}{rl}
            \textit{To}: & Jane Doe, ABC-DE, PO 5125\\
            \textit{From}: &John Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5125\\
            &Heather Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5125\\
            &W. Sam Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5126\\
            \textit{Thru}: &Chip Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5126\\
            \textit{Phone}: &(800)867-5309\\
            \textit{Symbol}: &ABC-DEF:2021-XXXX\\
            \textit{Date}: &\today \\
        \end{tabular}
    }
    %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
    
    %%%%%LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
    \fancyhead[L]{%% changed <<<<<<
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
        ABC-DEF:2021-XXXXX \\[5pt]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}\\[5pt]
        \Large\textbf{memorandum}\\[5pt]
        ORG-NAM, SOME ORGANIZATION
    \end{tabular}
    }
    %%%%%END LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
    
    %%%%%CENTER HEADER%%%%%
    \chead[C]{}
    %%%%%END CENTER HEADER%%%%%
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %                  FOOTERS                             %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
    
    %%%%%%%%CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \cfoot[C]{}
    %%%%%%%%END CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    %%%%%LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
\fancyfoot[L]{\vspace*{0pt}\fbox{% changed <<<<<<
            \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}                 \
            \centering\textbf{BLAH}\\                                       
            \raggedright    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
            \end{minipage}
        }%End of fbox
    }
    %%%%%END LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
    
    %%%%%RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\vspace*{0pt}\fbox{%
            \begin{minipage}[r]{0.4\textwidth}              
                \centering\large \textbf{Chief Editor}\\                
                \raggedright    \textbf{Brought to you by:} ME\\
                \textbf{Original:} XZ-ORG1-COMPANY
            \end{minipage}
        }%end of fbox
    }
    %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
    
}%End of first page definitions


\fancypagestyle{otherpages}{%all otherpages
\fancyhf{}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %                  HEADERS                             %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    %%%%%RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
    \fancyhead[R]{\today}
    %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
    
    %%%%%LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
    \fancyhead[LH]{\vspace{1cm}ABC-DEF: 2021-XXXXX}
    %%%%%END LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
    
    %%%%%CENTER HEADER%%%%%
    \fancyhead[C]{{\Huge\color{red}\textbf{HEAD/ER}}\\-\thepage}
    %%%%%END CENTER HEADER%%%%%
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %                  FOOTERS                             %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    %%%%%%%%CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \fancyfoot[C]{\Huge\color{red}\textbf{FOOT/ER}}
    %%%%%%%%END CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    
    %%%%%LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    %%%%%END LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
    
    %%%%%RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
    %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
    
}%end of all other pages

%%End of first page definition
\pagestyle{otherpages} % activate style to by used from the second page

\begin{document}
    
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\newgeometry{letterpaper,left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=3.5in, bottom=1.8in,headheight=2.5in}
{\noindent\Large \textbf{Subject: (U) poop}}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\afterpage{\globaldefs=1 \restoregeometry} % see reference https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358322/161015

\lipsum[1-10]
    
\end{document}
```

As a simpler **second alternative**, without using `afterpage` nor `\restoregeometry`, you  can leave some vertical space on the first page, to make place for the expanded heading, and then  `\pagestyle{otherpages}` will start from the second page onwards. (Similar to this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577066/161015)

[image: d2]

With the same preamble use

```
\begin{document}
    
\vspace*{1.5in} % added <<<<<<<<

\thispagestyle{firstpage}
{\noindent\Large \textbf{Subject: (U) poop}}
\vspace{0.5cm}  
    
\lipsum[1-10]
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `geometry` to enlarge the header and/or footer, it is generally advisable to include the `includeheadfoot` option, so that `geometry` will adapt the `textheight`.

For the first page, I would advise to put what is in your `firstpage` header, not in the header but in the text after the `\begin{document}`. If you want to specify it in the preamble the you can put it in `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

If you still want to do it with a header, my advise is to fool LaTeX by making the header appear to be of a normal header height (e.g. 10pt) and leave out the `\newgeometry`. In this way you can have your geometry the same on all pages. But then you have to compensate by starting the document with a `\vspace` to make up for the real header height.

You can fake the header height by putting it in a `\raisebox` and specifying the required height (e.g. 10pt) and depth (0pt). As `\raisebox` only accepts horizontal material, you have to put the left header inside a `\parbox` inside the `\raisebox`. You will have to fiddle a bit with the amount the boxes will be raised to get a proper positioning.

Here is a rough example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PAGE STYLE       %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
  {%First page definitions
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      %                  HEADERS                             %
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

      %%%%%RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
      \fancyhead[R]{\raisebox{-5cm}[10pt][0pt]{%
        \begin{tabular}{r@{}c@{}l}
          \textit{To}: & Jane Doe, ABC-DE, PO 5125\\
          \textit{From}: &John Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5125\\
          &Heather Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5125\\
          &W. Sam Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5126\\
          \textit{Thru}: &Chip Doe, ABC-DEF, PO 5126\\
          \textit{Phone}: &(800)867-5309\\
          \textit{Symbol}: &ABC-DEF:2021-XXXX\\
          \textit{Date}: &\today \\
        \end{tabular}}
      }
          %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
      \fancyhead[L]{\raisebox{-3cm}[10pt][0pt]{\parbox{0.5\headwidth}{\vspace{1cm}ABC-DEF:2021-XXXXX \\ [1cm]
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}\\
                    \vspace{0.1cm}{\Large\textbf{memorandum}}\\
                    ORG-NAM, SOME ORGANIZATION
  }}}
  %%%%%END LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%CENTER HEADER%%%%%
  \chead[C]{}
  %%%%%END CENTER HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %                  FOOTERS                             %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  

  %%%%%%%%CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cfoot[C]{}
  %%%%%%%%END CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  %%%%%LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  \lfoot{\vspace{0cm}\fbox{
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
          \begin{center}
            {\large\textbf{BLAH}}
          \end{center}
          blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        \end{minipage}
      }%End of fbox
    }
  %%%%%END LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%

  %%%%%RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\raisebox{-40pt}[10pt]{\fbox{\raggedright
        \begin{minipage}[r]{0.4\textwidth}
          \begin{center}
            {\large \textbf{Chief Editor}}
          \end{center}
          \textbf{Brought to you by:} ME\\
          \textbf{Original:} XZ-ORG1-COMPANY\\
        \end{minipage}
      }%end of fbox
    }}
    %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  
}%End of first page definitions


\fancypagestyle{otherpages}{%all otherpages
    \setlength{\headheight}{57.7pt}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %                  HEADERS                             %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  %%%%%RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
  \fancyhead[R]{\today}
  %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%
  \fancyhead[LH]{\vspace{1cm}ABC-DEF: 2021-XXXXX}
  %%%%%END LEFT SIDE HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%CENTER HEADER%%%%%
   \fancyhead[C]{{\Huge\color{red}\textbf{HEAD/ER}}\\-\thepage}
   %%%%%END CENTER HEADER%%%%%

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %                  FOOTERS                             %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  
  %%%%%%%%CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \cfoot[C]{\Huge\color{red}\textbf{FOOT/ER}}
  %%%%%%%%END CENTER FOOTER%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


  %%%%%LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  \fancyfoot[L]{}
  %%%%%END LEFT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%

  %%%%%RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  \fancyfoot[R]{}
  %%%%%END RIGHT SIDE FOOTER%%%%%
  
}%end of all other pages


%%End of first page definition
\pagestyle{otherpages}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\vspace*{7cm}

{\Large \textbf{Subject: (U) poop}}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\Blindtext
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]